# Expire passwords for all users at once

Tags: linux, security

In order to expire a user's password (and lock them out if they do not change their password in 10 days), I run the following commands:

```
sudo chage -d  0 [username]
sudo chage -l 10 [username]
```

I just updated the password policy using PAM, and I would like to require all users to update their passwords in accordance with the policy.  Instead of typing their names one by one, is there a way to run the above commands for all users that have an account on my Ubuntu server?

Comment: The typical Linux approach would be a oneliner that loops over each entry in passwd file. 
`for username in $(tail - n 100 /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1) do ...` or use `awk -F: '{print $1}' ` instead of `cut`. -   Please be careful that you only set password expiry for accounts that belong to actual people and not on service accounts like `daemon` `cups` `www-data` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 sudo awk -F: '$3 > 100 { system("chage -d 0 -l 10 "$1) }' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Although your awk is pretty nifty please also try to explain what scipts/code  should be doing for the lesser gods. I.E. *"Use awk to exclude reserved account names with uid numbers below 100 and apply password aging to all other user accounts in a single command:"*. - I think most Linux distributions assign user accounts UID numbers greater than 1000 rather 100 and I thought that `chage` takes a login `$1` and not an UID `$3` as the argument?